# Why is the cookie expiration date not surviving across sessions in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I made some changes to the testbed page, so I could make my question clearer here.

The page has three buttons: Set; Clear; and Get.

**Set** has this code:

```
PreferredCookie = new HttpCookie("PreferredCookie");
PreferredCookie.Value = "Chocolate Chip";
DateTime exp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1.0d);
PreferredCookie.Expires = exp;
Response.Cookies.Set(PreferredCookie);
```

**Clear** has this:

```
HttpCookie PreferredCookie = Request.Cookies["PreferredCookie"];
if (PreferredCookie != null)
{
    PreferredCookie.Value = "";
    PreferredCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now;
    Response.Cookies.Set(PreferredCookie);
}
```

**Get** has this, which outputs to an asp:Literal:

```
HttpCookie PreferredCookie = Request.Cookies["PreferredCookie"];
if (PreferredCookie != null)
{
    CookieLiteral.Text = "Value = " + PreferredCookie.Value + "<br>";
    CookieLiteral.Text += "Expires = " + PreferredCookie.Expires.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
else
{
    CookieLiteral.Text = "<h2>No Cookie?</h2>";
}
```

If I start the page and click on Clear, and then follow-up with the Get, I see:

> No Cookie?

If I then click the Set, then Get, I see:

> Value = Chocolate Chip
>  
>   Expires = 01/01/0001 00:00:00

This date seems to be treated as never expiring.  I get the same results if I access the page with Firefox.

Comment: Is that the only place in your project where you are setting that cookie?

Comment: Yes, @MikeSmithDev.  It is a test-bed project and just for trying out cookie handling.

Comment: How are you determining that the cookie is there and that the expiration date is from year 1?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I modified the question to make it clearer (I hope) and show all code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**The Short Answer -**  You cannot read the cookie's expiration date and time.

**Slightly Longer Answer -** This is not an issue of sessions in ASP.NET. It is an issue of what you can read from a cookie server-side in ASP.NET. [Per the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx):

> The browser is responsible for managing cookies, and the cookie's
>   expiration time and date help the browser manage its store of cookies.
>   Therefore, although you can read the name and value of a cookie, **you
>   cannot read the cookie's expiration date and time**. When the browser
>   sends cookie information to the server, the browser does not include
>   the expiration information. (The cookie's Expires property always
>   returns a date-time value of zero.)
>
> You can read the Expires property of a cookie that you have set in the
>   HttpResponse object, before the cookie has been sent to the browser.
>   **However, you cannot get the expiration back in the HttpRequest object.**

So basically, the cookie expiration date is set correctly. This can be verified by inspecting the cookie in the browser. Unfortunately, reading this cookie like in your **Get** function will return 1/1/0001.

If you really want to get the expiration, then you'd have to store it in the cookie itself:

**Set**

```
DateTime exp = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
HttpCookie PreferredCookie = new HttpCookie("PreferredCookie");
PreferredCookie.Values.Add("cookieType", "Zref");
PreferredCookie.Values.Add("exp", exp.ToString());
PreferredCookie.Expires = exp;
Response.Cookies.Set(PreferredCookie);
```

**Get**

```
HttpCookie PreferredCookie = Request.Cookies["PreferredCookie"];
if (PreferredCookie != null)
{
    CookieLiteral.Text = "Value = " + PreferredCookie["cookieType"] + "<br>";
    CookieLiteral.Text += "Expires = " + PreferredCookie["exp"];
}
else
{
    CookieLiteral.Text = "No Cookie";
}
```

Comment: OMG, all this time (never having worked with cookies before, after all these years), I had made the assumption the expiration date was readable.  What I was trying to do was verify that the information in the cookie was set properly.  It's kind of embarrassing, in a way.  But I thank you sincerely for fixing my misunderstanding!

Comment: You can't trust anything about a cookie, so this makes sense on some level.  At best... if a browser does send a cookie, you have to verify everything about it.  As a result, it doesn't even make sense to look at an expiration date, since it's not trustworthy.  At best, it's a client-side indicator of whether or not to even bother sending the cookie to the server.

Comment: Wish I found your comment two hours ago... :-)  Spent HOURS trying to figure out why I could not see the expiration of the cookie server side!  THANK YOU MikeSmithDev!